# Data Preprocessing with python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql-9.1

I am using python for reading Unicode data and then Preprocessing it and storing it in a database (Postgres)

Now the database has 3 tables with 4 attributes and 700,000 tuples each. I read the data and map it to python dictionary and list according to the way I need to use it.

Now I have to iterate through all these tuples, do some calculations and write again in the database.

I have to do 1000 iteration like these. The problem is 1 iteration takes about 50 minutes which makes it impossible to make those many iterations.

Is there anyway I can make these iterations faster?

Any new idea is welcome. Not necessary in python.

Comment: To me this sounds as if this is better done using a single UPDATE rather then 700.000 single updates. **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: The dataset is not in English. I will still edit the post with a dummy dataset. Now about the updates. I am updating once only. There are no single updates. I take the whole data as python lists ( will be changing to pandas soon ) then iterating and doing all calculations and updating the database with concatenated update commands in a single go. The time taken by a single iteration is my concern. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what updates each "iteration" performs, but clearly you are reading and writing 7 million rows. Would it be possible to use the database to perform the updates?

Comment: Thanx for the help. First of all 0.7 million rows in my db. Just giving a vague idea of data. Secondly about the updates - I take a tuple. See one of its attributes( say A ) and fetch all tuples with same attribute value. Then update the tuple's another attribute ( say B )value with avg of all values ( of B in other tuples with A bring same ). This happens in 2 tables.

Comment: After getting the 2 new updated values I multiply them and store in third table at appropriate place.

Comment: I was thinking about the same as you suggested. But I don't know how much faster will an iteration in the db may be. Iteration is taking 50 min with python. Reducing it to 40 with DB is not what I want. I want about 6-8 iteration an hour.